# Example of a function which is continuous in $\mathbb{R}_K$ but not in $\mathbb{R}_u$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Let $\mathbb{R}_u$ be $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the usual topology and $\mathbb{R}_K$ be $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the [$K$-topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-topology).

Is there a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous when the domain is $\mathbb{R}_K$ but not when it is $\mathbb{R}_u$? (The codomain is taken with usual topology in both cases.)

Comment: @RabiKumarChakraborty You're viewing it from the wrong way. What you're saying proves that anything continuous in $\mathbb{R}_u$ is also continuous in $\mathbb{R}_K$. I want the converse.

Comment: Oh, sorry Sayantan Da, I didn't see your comment after deleting that of mine, and yes I viewed it wrong and so I deleted my comment . Thanks for identifying my mistake . And, +1 from me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  More generally, for any regular space $X$, the continuous maps $\mathbb{R}_K\to X$ and $\mathbb{R}_u\to X$ are the same.  To prove this, suppose $f:\mathbb{R}_K\to X$ is continuous and let $U\subseteq X$ be open.  Since $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}_K$, it contains an open interval around all its points except for possibly $0$, so we just have to show it contains an open interval around $0$ if $0\in f^{-1}(U)$.  Now note that by regularity, there is a closed neighborhood $C$ of $f(0)$ contained in $U$.  Thus $f^{-1}(C)\subseteq f^{-1}(U)$ is a closed neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}_K$.  But the closure of any neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}_K$ contains an open interval around $0$ (since $1/n$ will be in the closure for all sufficiently large $n$), and so $f^{-1}(U)$ does contain an open interval around $0$.